# Parsing XML file with same tagnames in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml

I have an XML file (excerpt from it):

```
<regions_list>
    <region type="continent" name="europe"
        translate="=Europe" inner_download_suffix="europe" boundary="no" poly_extract="europe">

<!-- north-europe -->
        <region name="denmark" lang="da" poly_extract="north-europe"/>
        <region name="estonia" lang="et" poly_extract="north-europe"/>
        <region name="iceland" lang="is" poly_extract="north-europe"/>
        <region name="faroe-islands" translate="Faroe Islands;entity=node" lang="fo" poly_extract="north-europe"/>
        <region name="finland" inner_download_prefix="$name" srtm="no" lang="fi,sv" poly_extract="north-europe">
            <region map="no" name="aland" translate="name:fi=Ahvenanmaa;admin_level=3;entity=relation"/>
            <region type="srtm" name="eastern-finland" translate="Eastern Finland;entity=relation"/>
            <region name="northern-finland" map="no" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="name:en=Northern Finland;entity=relation" boundary="no">
                <region type="srtm" name="lapland" translate="Lapland;entity=relation"/>
                <region type="srtm" name="northern-ostrobothnia" translate="name:en=Northern Ostrobothnia;entity=relation"/>
            </region>
            <region type="srtm" name="southern-finland" translate="Southern Finland;entity=relation"/>
            <region type="srtm" name="western-finland" translate="Western Finland;entity=relation"/>
        </region>
        <region name="latvia" lang="lv" poly_extract="north-europe"/>
        <region name="lithuania" lang="lt" poly_extract="north-europe"/>
        <region name="norway" srtm="no" inner_download_prefix="$name" lang="nb,nn" poly_extract="north-europe" join_map_files="yes">
            <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="akershus"/>
            <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="astfold" translate="Østfold;entity=node"/>
            <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="aust-agder"/>
            <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="buskerud"/>
            <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="finnmark"/>
            <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="hedmark"/>
            <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="hordaland"/>
            <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="more-og-romsdal" translate="Møre og Romsdal;entity=node"/>
            <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="nordland"/>
            <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="nord-trondelag" translate="Nord-Trøndelag;entity=node"/>
            <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="oppland"/>
            <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="oslo"/>
            <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="rogaland"/>
            <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="sogn-og-fjordane" translate="Sogn og Fjordane;entity=node"/>
            <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="sor-trondelag" translate="Sør-Trøndelag;entity=node"/>
            <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="telemark"/>
            <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="troms"/>
            <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="vest-agder"/>
            <region srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="vestfold"/>
            <region name="svalbard-and-jan-mayen" translate="Svalbard;entity=relation"/>
        </region>
        <region name="sweden" inner_download_prefix="$name" srtm="no" lang="sv" poly_extract="north-europe">
            <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="blekinge" translate="Blekinge län;entity=relation"/>
            <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="dalarna" translate="Dalecarlia;entity=relation"/>
            <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="gavleborg" translate="Gävleborgs län;entity=relation"/>
            <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="gotland" translate="Gotlands län;entity=relation"/>
            <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="halland" translate="Hallands län;entity=relation"/>
            <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="jamtland" translate="Jämtlands län;entity=relation"/>
            <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="jonkoping" translate="Jönköpings län;entity=relation"/>
            <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="kalmar" translate="Kalmar län;entity=relation"/>
            <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="kronoberg" translate="Kronobergs län;entity=relation"/>
            <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="norrbotten" translate="Norrbottens län;entity=relation"/>
            <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="orebro" translate="Örebro län;entity=relation"/>
            <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="ostergotland" translate="Östergötlands län;entity=relation"/>
            <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="skane" translate="Skåne län;entity=relation"/>
            <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="sodermanland" translate="Södermanlands län;entity=relation"/>
            <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="stockholm" translate="Stockholms län;entity=relation"/>
            <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="uppsala" translate="Uppsala län;entity=relation"/>
            <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="varmland" translate="Värmlands län;entity=relation"/>
            <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="vasterbotten" translate="Västerbottens län;entity=relation"/>
            <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="vasternorrland" translate="Västernorrlands län;entity=relation"/>
            <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="vastmanland" translate="Västmanlands län;entity=relation"/>
            <region map="yes" srtm="yes" hillshade="no" wiki="no" name="vastra-gotaland" translate="Västra Götalands län;entity=relation"/>
        </region>

<!-- east-europe -->
        <region name="belarus" lang="be,ru" poly_extract="east-europe"/>
        <region name="bulgaria" lang="bg" poly_extract="east-europe"/>
        <region name="czech-republic" inner_download_prefix="$name" translate="Czech Republic;entity=node" lang="cs,sk" poly_extract="east-europe" join_map_files="yes">
            <region name="jihovychod" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="name:en=Southeast;ref=CZ06;entity=relation"/>
            <region name="jihozapad" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="name:en=Southwest;ref=CZ03;entity=relation"/>
            <region name="moravskoslezsko" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="name:en=Moravia-Silesia;entity=relation"/>
            <region name="praha" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="name:en=Prague;entity=relation"/>
            <region name="severovychod" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="name:en=Northeast;ref=CZ05;entity=relation"/>
            <region name="severozapad" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="name:en=Northwest;ref=CZ04;entity=relation"/>
            <region name="stredni-cechy" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="name:en=Central Bohemia;entity=relation"/>
            <region name="stredni-morava" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="name:en=Central Moravia;entity=relation"/>
        </region>
        <region name="hungary" lang="hu" poly_extract="east-europe"/>
        <region name="moldova" lang="ro" poly_extract="east-europe"/>
        <region name="poland" inner_download_prefix="$name" lang="pl" poly_extract="east-europe" join_map_files="yes">
            <region name="greater-poland" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="Greater Poland;entity=node"/>
            <region name="kuyavian-pomeranian" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="Kuyavian-Pomerania;entity=node"/>
            <region name="lesser-poland" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="Lesser Poland;entity=node"/>
            <region name="lodz" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="Łódź;entity=node"/>
            <region name="lower-silesian" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="Lower Silesia;entity=node"/>
            <region name="lublin" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="name:en=Lublin Voivodeship;entity=relation"/>
            <region name="lubusz" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no"/>
            <region name="masovian" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="Masovia;entity=node"/>
            <region name="opole" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="Opole Voivodeship;entity=node"/>
            <region name="podlachian" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="Podlachia;entity=node"/>
            <region name="pomeranian" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="Pomerania;entity=node"/>
            <region name="silesian" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="Silesia;entity=node"/>
            <region name="subcarpathian" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="Subcarpathia;entity=node"/>
            <region name="swietokrzyskie" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="Holy Cross;entity=node"/>
            <region name="warmian-masurian" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="Warmian-Masurian Voivodeship;entity=node"/>
            <region name="west-pomeranian" srtm="no" hillshade="no" wiki="no" translate="West Pomerania;entity=node"/>
        </region>
```

I try to extract all 'name' attributes of the childNodes of the Europe region (`<region type="continent" name="europe"...>`, but I get only names of the first 5 elements . If thos countries have childNodes, I need to extract them too, but I my primarily goal for now is countries. The region with name attribute 'finland' has childNodes itself, but the parser looks through the first child with name="aland" and breaks out of the loop alltogether.

```
 public static Region parsedXMLForEurope(String xmlFile) {
    List<Region> allRegions = new ArrayList<>();
    Region region = new Region("Europe");

    try {
        XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        XmlPullParser parser = factory.newPullParser();
        parser.setInput(new StringReader(xmlFile));
        int eventType = parser.getEventType();

        while(eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            Log.i("XMLParser", "******************");
            Log.i("XMLParser", "Current counrtry is: " + parser.getAttributeValue(null, "name"));

            switch (eventType) {
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    if(parser.getName().equals("region") && parser.getAttributeValue(null, "poly_extract").contains("europe")) {
                        Log.i("XMLParser", "******************");
                        Log.i("XMLParser", "Current country is: " + parser.getAttributeValue(null, "name"));
                        region.pushRegion(new Region(parser.getAttributeValue(null, "name")));
                    }
                    break;

                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    Log.i("XMLParser", "******************");
                    Log.i("XMLParser", "Current country is: " + parser.getAttributeValue(null, "name"));
                    break;

            }
            eventType = parser.next();
        }
    } catch (Exception e ){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return region;
}
```

Log Messages: 
[LogMessages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbFyD.jpg)

Comment: You are still not giving examples. Please do. Give two examples. One that goes ok. One that fails.

Comment: `extract all names of the countries in that region`. I can see what you mean with region as it is a tag. But what are countries? There is no county/countries tag. So if you wanna specify what should happen you should use other words.

Comment: I've editted and hope this time it is more clear.

Comment: You have no log statement for the end tag. Put it in as now you do not know when it breaks the loop.  Report us when it breaks.

Comment: Why are you messing around with  "poly_extract").contains("europe")) ?

Comment: You should post the logfile so we can see what is found and printed. And where it stops. As you are not telling us that.

Comment: `of the Europe region`. Well i would call that of continent europe.

Comment: I use "poly_extract" as it is the only common search parameter I can think of.

Comment: I've appended an image file of the Log Messages

Comment: Common search parameter? Do the children of finland have the poly_extract attribute?

Comment: Funny: you did not report that NullPointerException. You have it because the poly_extract attribute does not exist there. So it is null. You should check for null before use.

Comment: Well not funny at all that you did not report the exception. Please be serious when you ask for help. And post logcats as text. Not as images. Just put them in a code block here.

Comment: I'm very grateful for your help. This was my first question on StackOverflow, so it was extremely useful that you helped me to clear all the ambiguities I've unintentionally provided.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried :

```
JSONObject jsonObj = XML.toJSONObject(xmlFile);
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONObject("region").getJSONArray("region");
JSONObject jsonObjFromJsonArray = jsonArray.toJSONObject(0);
JSONObject jsonArrayObjForCountryRegion = jsonObjFromJsonArray.getJSONObject("region");
```

And then you can use it as a JSON object .. it will be very easy to access data instead of parsing XML content.

Comment: I'll try that. Thanks!

Comment: I have updated my answer for depth accessing to your XML content .. Hope it helps you :)